# Is BOOL read/write atomic in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, atomic, boolean

What happens when two threads set a BOOL to YES "at the same time"?

Comment: It opens a wormhole to another dimension.

Comment: If they're both setting it to `YES`, there can't be a problem whether the write is atomic or not, can there?

Comment: @CarlNorum that might be true but its not obvious to me why

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Without a locking construct, reading/writing any type variable is NOT atomic in Objective C.

If two threads write YES at the same time to a BOOL, the result is YES regardless of which one gets in first.

Please see: [Synchronizing Thread Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html)

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. If one thread sets it to YES while another is setting it to NO, can there be memory corruption?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html gives a very thorough discussion.  I think I will use an int instead of a BOOL, and use the OSAtomic operations on this int.

Comment: The implication of your question is whether or not some other chunk of memory might be crunched. No;  that can't happen.  The worst that'll happen is you'll read a NO seemingly after you wrote a YES in another thread.

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to switch to int32_t instead of BOOL, and use OSAtomicAnd32Barrier and OSAtomicOr32Barrier to set and unset my flag.

Comment: Mr Wheat, Would you care to elaborate why single byte POD such as BOOL could be possibly nonatomic even if declared as such? Here is what google search for "arm store single byte vs word" http://www.heyrick.co.uk/assembler/str.html -> there are dedicated instructions for storing and loading single byte from memory LDRB & STRB

Comment: And yes, I looked at the link you've provided: the synchronization primitives start with 32 bit int. There is NOTHING for 8 and 16 bit PODs

Answer (score 8):

Here is code for solution suggested by [Jacko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/244005/jacko).
Use `volatile` `uint32_t` with `OSAtomicOr32Barrier` and `OSAtomicAnd32Barrier`

```
#import <libkern/OSAtomic.h>

volatile uint32_t _IsRunning;

- (BOOL)isRunning {
    return _IsRunning != 0;
}

- (void)setIsRunning:(BOOL)allowed {

    if (allowed) {
        OSAtomicOr32Barrier(1, & _IsRunning); //Atomic bitwise OR of two 32-bit values with barrier
    } else {
        OSAtomicAnd32Barrier(0, & _IsRunning); //Atomic bitwise AND of two 32-bit values with barrier.
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! But why don't just use `OSAtomicOr32Barrier(allowed, & _IsRunning);` instead of conditional statement?

Comment: Ah, it is not so simple, sorry. You can't use "or" version to reset the flag, i.e. you must use "and" version to do this (OSAtomicAnd32Barrier).

Answer (score 5):

I would have to diverge from the accepted answer. Sorry.
While objective c does not guarantee that BOOL properties declared as nonatomic
are in fact atomic I'd have to guess that the hardware you most
care about (all iOS and macos devices) have instructions to perform byte reads and stores atomically. So, unless Apple comes out with Road Light OS running
on an IBM microcontroller that has 5 bit wide bus to send 10 bit bytes over
you could just as well use nonatomic BOOLs in a situation that calls for atomic BOOLs. The code would not be portable to Road Light OS but if you can 
sacrifice the futureproofing of your code nonatomic is fine for this use case.
I'm sure there are hardened individuals on s.o. that would raise to the challenge of disassembling synthesized BOOL getter and setter for atomic/nonatomic cases to see what's the difference. At least on ARM.

Your takeaway from this is likely this

1. you can declare BOOL properties as atomic and it won't cost you a dime
   on all HW iOS and macOS intrinsically supports.
2. memory barriers are orthogonal to atomicity
3. you most definitely should not use 4 byte properties to store booleans into
   unless you are into [very] fuzzy logic.
   It's idiotic and wasteful, you don't want to be a clone of a Java programmer,
   who can't tell a float from a double, or do you?
4. BOOL variables (which do not obviously support atomic/nonatomic decorators
   would not be atomic on some narrow bus architectures objective C would
   not be used on anyway (microcontrollers with or without some [very] micro OS are C & assembly territory I suppose. they don't typically need the luggage
   objc runtime would bring)

Answer (score 5):

> What happens when two threads set a BOOL to YES "at the same time"?

Then its value will be `YES`. If to threads write the same value to the same memory location, the memory location will have that value, whether that is atomic or not plays no role. It would only play a role if two threads write a different value to the same memory location or if one thread writes to it while another one is reading from it.

> Is BOOL read/write atomic in Objective C?

It is if your hardware is a Macintosh running macOS. `BOOL` is `uint32_t` on PPC systems and `char` on Intel systems and writing these data types is atomic on their respective systems.

The Obj-C language makes no such guarantee, though. On other systems it depends on your compiler used and how `BOOL` is defined for that platfrom. Most compilers (gcc, clang, ...) guarantee that writing a variable of `int`-size is always atomic, whether other sizes are atomic depends on the CPU.

Note that atomic is not the same as thread-safe. Writing a `BOOL` is not a memory barrier. The compiler and the CPU may reorder instructions around a `BOOL` write:

```
a = 10;
b = YES;
c = 20;
```

There is no guarantee that instructions are executed in that order. The fact that `b` is `YES` does not mean that `a` is 10. The compiler and CPU are free to shuffle these three instructions around as desired since they don't depend on each other. Explicit atomic instructions as well as locks, mutexes and semaphores are usually memory barriers, that means they instruct the compiler and CPU to not move instructions located before that operation beyond it and not move instructions located after that operation before it (it's a hard border, that instructions may not pass).

Also cache consistency is not guaranteed. Even after you set a `BOOL` to `YES`, some other thread may still see it as `NO` for a limited amount of time. Memory barrier operations are usually also operations that ensure cache synchronization among all threads/cores/CPUs in the system.

And to add something really useful here as well, this is how you can ensure that setting a boolean value is atomic and acts as a memory barrier in 2020 using C11 which will also work in Obj-C Code:

```
#import <stdatomic.h>

// ...

volatile atomic_bool b = true;

// ...

atomic_store(&b, true);

// ...

atomic_store(&b, false);
```

Not only will this code guarantee atomic writes to the bool (for which the system will choose an appropriate type), it will also act as a memory barrier (Sequentially Consistent).

To read the boolean atomically from another thread, you'd use

```
bool x = atomic_load(&b);
```

You can also use `atomic_load_explicit` and `atomic_store_explicit` and pass an explicit memory order, which allows you to control more fine grained which kind of memory reordering is allowed and which ones is not.

Learn more about your possibilities here:

http://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html

Always read "Notes for optimizers" to see which memory reordering is allowed. If in doubt, always use Sequentially Consistent (`memory_order_seq_cst`, which is the default if not specified). It will not result in fastest performance but it's the safest option and you really should only use something else if you know what you are doing.